# error: cannot find symbol while passing value

Tags: java

I instantiate an object with two parameters.  While trying to pass another value (variable "interest").

I get error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    investor1.initialize(interest);
             ^
```

symbol:   method initialize(double)
  location: variable investor1 of type Investor
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Do I need to create another object? or what would be the right way to pass this value?

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    Investor investor1 = new Investor (1001, 2000); //

    System.out.print("Please enter the Annual Interest Rate you hope to earn; ");
    double interest = stdIn.nextDouble();

    investor1.initialize(interest); //here is where I get the error.

    System.out.println("Monthly balances for one year with " + interest + " annual interest:");
    System.out.printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s", "Month", "Account #", "Balance");
    System.out.printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\n", "-----", "---------", "-------");



    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

        System.out.printf("\n%5d\t%9d\t%7.2f", i, investor1.getAccount(),investor1.getBalance());
    }
```

Second part of code:

```
    public class Investor{

    private double interest;
    private final int Account_Number;
    private double balance;
    //***********************************************************
    public Investor(int account, double bal){
        this.Account_Number = account;
        this.balance = bal;
    }
   //********************************************************************
    public void initialize(double temp){
        this.interest = temp;
    }

    public double getInt(){
        return interest;
    }

    public int getAccount(){
        return this.Account_Number;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return this.balance;
    }
}//end of investor
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You need to include the full error message.

Comment: Do you have your ending bracket for the main method?

Comment: @3kings Yes I do have the ending brackets.

Comment: @Elrascabuches Okay do you mind posting the full error in a readable format?

Comment: @3kings my bad, the format changed while copy pasting.

Comment: @Elrascabuches I don't get any errors when running this code. As Long as your `Runner` class or w.e. has that main in has an ending bracket for the `main` (not visible in code provided) and the class is properly made

Comment: @3kings Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I reconstructed your code as below and the error is gone (also it is executable). Please take a look and see if you can run it without the exception:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Investor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Investor investor1 = new Investor(1001, 2000); //

        System.out.print("Please enter the Annual Interest Rate you hope to earn; ");
        double interest = stdIn.nextDouble();

        investor1.initialize(interest); // here is where I get the error.

        System.out.println("Monthly balances for one year with " + interest + " annual interest:");
        System.out.printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s", "Month", "Account #", "Balance");
        System.out.printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\n", "-----", "---------", "-------");

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            System.out.printf("\n%5d\t%9d\t%7.2f", i, investor1.getAccount(), investor1.getBalance());
        }
    }

    private double interest;
    private final int Account_Number;
    private double balance;

    // ***********************************************************
    public Investor(int account, double bal) {
        this.Account_Number = account;
        this.balance = bal;
    }

    // ********************************************************************
    public void initialize(double temp) {
        this.interest = temp;
    }

    public double getInt() {
        return interest;
    }

    public int getAccount() {
        return this.Account_Number;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return this.balance;
    }
}// end of investor
```